# Error while applying style.map function

Tags: python, dataframe

i am using dataframe style.map function to color my  table cells based on some condtion,using the code below

```
def color(s):
    for i in range (1,12):
        if s.iloc[i]<s.iloc[0]:
            return 'color: green'
        else:
            return 'color: red'
df3.style.apply(color,axis=1)
```

but i am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

i feel my syntax is correct and if i am printing something inside the function then it's printing and after that giving this error.
why i am getting this error?

Comment: Why does this function iterate over `range(1,12)`?  It always returns something, thus exiting the function, on the very first iteration.  It will _never_ get to i=2.

Comment: yes yes..that was the problem. it should return a list instead of just a single value.Thanks!!